# how to replace Array with number and then will be sort by number?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [Asia] => Array
        (
            [Edisi] => 187September2001

    [Hongkong] => Array
        (
            [Edisi] => 193Oktober2001

    [1 India] => Array
        (
            [Edisi] => 176September2001

    [2 India] => Array
        (
            [Edisi] => 177September2001

         ) 
     )
```

How can I replace the country name with number and then I will be sort with number, like:

```
"hongkong" => 1,
"1 India" => 2,
"2 India" => 3,
"Asia" => 4,
```

Comment: Any reason there's numbers inside the strings with the country names?

Comment: Do you want to keep the order of the countries as they were in the initial array? I can't seem to work out why you have "Asia" as your last key in the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$keys = array_keys($array)` to extract the keys of your array.

This should give an array like this:

```
array(
  [0] => Hongkong
  [1] => 1 India
  [2] => 2 India
)
```

Then generate an array for your index:

```
$index = range(1, count($keys));
```

Then combine your index and keys:

```
$result = array_combine($keys, $index);
```

This should result in:

```
array(
    [Hongkong] => 1
    [1 India] => 2
    [2 India] => 3
)
```